# Match values equal or less than, by group

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with columns :

```
ID = c("AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAJCQ","AAJCQ",
       "AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ")

value = c(0,0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.006,0,0.000333,0.0005,
          0.001,0.002,0.002333,0.003667,0.023,0.0245)

newval = c(0.990295749,0.993992606,0.994454713,0.995378928,0.995841035,
           0.996303142,0.989833641,0.990295749,0.990757856,0.99676525,0.997227357,
           0.997689464,0.998151571,0.998613678,0.999075786)
```

and the corresponding data frame:

```
ID     value      newval
AAHON   0         0.990295749
AAHON   0.001     0.993992606
AAHON   0.002     0.994454713
AAHON   0.003     0.995378928
AAHON   0.004     0.995841035
AAHON   0.006     0.996303142
AAJCQ   0         0.989833641
AAJCQ   0.000333  0.990295749
AAJCQ   0.0005    0.990757856
AAJCQ   0.001     0.99676525
AAJCQ   0.002     0.997227357
AAJCQ   0.002333  0.997689464
AAJCQ   0.003667  0.998151571
AAJCQ   0.023     0.998613678
AAJCQ   0.0245    0.999075786
```

I need a function that returns a line for each value that matches exactly the corresponding value in the second column, and for each group. For example, if I ask for "0.002" then the expected output would be:

```
ID      value   newval
AAHON   0.002   0.994454713
AAJCQ   0.002   0.997227357
```

This is quite trivial and easy to do. However, I also need for this function to return the value right before the one I ask if it doesn't exist in the group. For example, if I ask for "0.005", then the expected output would be:

```
ID      value       newval
AAHON   0.004       0.995841035
AAJCQ   0.003667    0.998151571
```

In the case of a value present in one group but not the other (e.g. "0.003") the result would look like:

```
ID      value       newval
AAHON   0.003       0.995378928
AAJCQ   0.002333    0.997689464
```

Comment: I think relevant search terms here would be "rolling join by group".

Answer (score 2):

**`filter` and `slice_max`**: After filtering for values smaller or equal to target value, using `slice_max` will give us the closest value.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter(value<=0.003) %>% 
  slice_max(value, by = ID)
```

or as a function:

```
closest_leq <- function(dat, grp, val_col, val){
  require(dplyr)
  
  dat %>% 
    filter({{ val_col }} <= val) %>% 
    slice_max({{ val_col }}, by = {{ grp }})
}

closest_leq(df1, ID, value, 0.003)
```

---

**`filter` with `abs`:** Also, we can first filter for values less than equal the target value and then filter for the value that is closest to the target value (smallest absolute difference).

```r
library(dplyr)  

df1 %>% 
  filter(value <= 0.003, .by = ID) %>% 
  filter(abs(value - 0.003) == min(abs(value - 0.003)), .by = ID)
```

Or if you want it as a function:

```
closest_leq <- function(dat, grp, val_col, val){
  require(dplyr)
  
  dat %>% 
    filter({{ val_col }} <= val, 
           .by = {{ grp }}) %>% 
    filter(abs({{ val_col }} - val) == min(abs({{ val_col }} - val)), 
           .by = {{ grp }})
}

closest_leq(df1, ID, value, 0.003)
```

---

Or in **`base`:**

```
subset(df1, value <= 0.003)[with(subset(df1, value <= 0.003), 
                                  ave(value, ID, FUN=max)==value),]
```

---

**Results:**

```
#>      ID    value    newval
#> 1 AAHON 0.003000 0.9953789
#> 2 AAJCQ 0.002333 0.9976895
```

---

If you want to check for *multiple values at once*, we can use `purrr::map_`:

```
# values to check, e.g.
x = c(0.002, 0.003, 0.005) 

purrr::map_dfr(x, ~closest_leq(df1, ID, value, .x))

     ID    value    newval
1 AAHON 0.002000 0.9944547
2 AAJCQ 0.002000 0.9972274
3 AAHON 0.003000 0.9953789
4 AAJCQ 0.002333 0.9976895
5 AAHON 0.004000 0.9958410
6 AAJCQ 0.003667 0.9981516
```

Or `base::findInterval` by group, using `by` or `ave`:

```
# by
do.call(rbind, 
        by(df1, df1$ID, \(dd) dd[findInterval(x, dd$value), ]))

# ave
df1[ave(df1$value, df1$ID, FUN = \(v) seq_along(v) %in% findInterval(x, v)) == 1, ]
```

---

#### Data:

```
data.frame(ID = c("AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAJCQ","AAJCQ",
                  "AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ"),
           value = c(0,0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.006,0,0.000333,0.0005,
                     0.001,0.002,0.002333,0.003667,0.023,0.0245),
           newval = c(0.990295749,0.993992606,0.994454713,0.995378928,0.995841035,
                      0.996303142,0.989833641,0.990295749,0.990757856,0.99676525,
                      0.997227357,0.997689464,0.998151571,0.998613678,0.999075786)) -> df1
```

Comment: @M-- you could also consider using the curly-curly `{{` operator in place of `!!enquo`.

Answer (score 1):

using the tidyverse tools

```
library(tidyverse)


ID = c("AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAHON","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ","AAJCQ")
value = c(0,0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.006,0,0.000333,0.0005,0.001,0.002,0.002333,0.003667,0.023,0.0245)
newval = c(0.990295749,0.993992606,0.994454713,0.995378928,0.995841035,0.996303142,0.989833641,0.990295749,0.990757856,0.99676525,0.997227357,0.997689464,0.998151571,0.998613678,0.999075786)
df=data.frame(ID,value, newval)

# set the value yo want yo ask for
ask=0.003

df %>% 
  filter(value<=ask) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(value, .by_group = T) %>% 
  slice_tail(n=1)
```

you get

```
  ID      value newval
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AAHON 0.003    0.995
2 AAJCQ 0.00233  0.998
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I could think of was to use the `dplyr` package in R.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID, value, newval)
val <- .0023

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
       filter(value <= val) %>% 
       arrange(value) %>% 
       filter(row_number() == n())
```

That gives you:

```
  ID    value newval
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AAHON 0.002  0.994
2 AAJCQ 0.002  0.997
```

Example with 0.005:

```
  ID      value newval
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AAJCQ 0.00367  0.998
2 AAHON 0.004    0.996
```

And with 0.003

```
  ID      value newval
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AAJCQ 0.00233  0.998
2 AAHON 0.003    0.995
```

Comment: try a number like 0.005 and see whether the code gives the expected results

Comment: Before `filter` you need to arrange the data. There is no guarantee that the data comes sorted. In that case, you basically have the same answer as Juan's but only using `filter(row_number() == n())` instead of `slice_...`.

Answer (score 0):

in Base R you can do:

```
merge(df, aggregate(value~ID, df, max, subset = value <= 0.005))
     ID    value    newval
1 AAHON 0.004000 0.9958410
2 AAJCQ 0.003667 0.9981516

merge(df, aggregate(value~ID, df, max, subset = value <= 0.002))
     ID value    newval
1 AAHON 0.002 0.9944547
2 AAJCQ 0.002 0.9972274
```

You can also do:

```
subset(df, ave(value<=0.005, ID, FUN=\(x)which.min(x)-1 == seq_along(x)))
      ID    value    newval
5  AAHON 0.004000 0.9958410
13 AAJCQ 0.003667 0.9981516

subset(df, ave(value<=0.002, ID, FUN=\(x)which.min(x)-1 == seq_along(x)))
      ID value    newval
3  AAHON 0.002 0.9944547
11 AAJCQ 0.002 0.9972274

subset(df, ave(value<=0.003, ID, FUN=\(x)which.min(x)-1 == seq_along(x)))
      ID    value    newval
4  AAHON 0.003000 0.9953789
12 AAJCQ 0.002333 0.9976895
```

Comment: Or `findInterval` (by group), so that you can check several values at once.